# Echo database user Name with Posted email

Tags: php, mysql, post, get, echo

I'm trying to get the user's name from a database after posting his email on a form but its not showing the name, if I add a success message it shows it so it's working but its not showing me the name :(

```html
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx");


$email = $_POST['email_r'];


$sqlr = "SELECT * FROM participantes WHERE email='$email'";
$result = $conn->query($sqlr);


if(!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "Email Incorrecto: No se a registrado.";
} else {
    echo "your name is: ->" . $row['name'] . " <- that is it.";
}

?>
```

Comment: Does your `participantes` table have a `name` column? I suggest you add this to the top of your script ~ `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

Comment: Also, you're wide open to SQL injection attacks here. You should be using a prepared statement and binding the `email` parameter. See https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd say your table does not have a `name` column. Either that or the matching record has an empty `name` value.

This should at least help you pinpoint any potential issues as well as resolve your SQL injection vulnerability...

```
<?php
// show any errors
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

// show all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// make MySQLi throw exceptions
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$conn = mysqli_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx");

// safely get the request parameter
$email = isset($_POST['email_r']) ? $_POST['email_r'] : null;

// Prepare a statement with a placeholder for the "email" parameter
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT `name` FROM `participantes` WHERE `email` = ?');

// bind the parameter
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
$stmt->execute();

// bind results. This seems easier than fetch_assoc IMHO
$stmt->bind_result($name);

// fetch records, if any
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo 'your name is: ->', $name, ' <- that is it.';
} else {
    echo "Email Incorrecto: No se a registrado.";
}

$stmt->close();
```